# Checkbox from telerik mvc grid not getting checked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik-mvc

I use checkbox from telerik mvc grid. I face a problem of my checkboxes not getting checked on the first click. On the second click,it gets checked, but while clicking on another checkbox, the previous checkbox gets unchecked. How do i solve this problem. This is the code which i used:

```
    @(Html.Telerik().Grid<PermissionMappingModel>()
                .Name("mAdministratorpermission-grid")
                .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(m => m.Id))
                .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
                .ToolBar(commands =>
                {
                    commands.SubmitChanges().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image).ImageHtmlAttributes(new { style = "margin-left:0" });

                })

                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(x => x.Id).Hidden(true);
                    columns.Bound(x => x.CategoryName).ReadOnly(true).Width(125);
                    columns.Bound(x => x.Name).ReadOnly(true).Width(200);
                    columns.Bound(x => x.IsAllowed)


                        .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='checkedRecords' value='<#= IsAllowed #>' />").Width(15).Centered();  


                })

                                                                       .DataBinding(
                                                                       dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
                                                                                       .Select("MAdminCustomerPermissionLoad", "Security")
                                                                                       .Update("MAdminSavePermission", "Security")
                                                                                       )

                                                                       .Groupable(grouping => grouping.Groups(groups => { groups.Add(c => c.CategoryName); }).Visible(false))
                                                                       .ClientEvents(events =>
                                                                       {
                                                                           events.OnDataBinding("OnMAdminPermissionViewDataBinding");
                                                                           events.OnSubmitChanges("OnMAdminPermissionSubmit");
                                                                           events.OnEdit("OnMAdminPermissionEdit");
                                                                       })

                                                                       .Sortable()

                                                                   )
```

Answer (score 1):

okay, first thing you need to change:

```
.ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='checkedRecords' value='<#= IsAllowed #>' />")
```

for:

```
.ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='checkedRecords' checked='<#= IsAllowed #>' />")
```

That should solve your first issue. For the second one, I might suggest enabling multiselect as in:

```
.Selectable(selection =>
                {
                    selection.Enabled(true);
                    selection.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple);
                })
```

but that is a long shot.
Hope this helps

Comment: As an addendum, the `checked` property checks the box whenever it is present, so what you're looking for is probably something more like `<# if (IsAllowed==true) {#> checked='checked' <# } #>`